# 80s/90s sitcom with a girl who could stop time and spoke to her dad through a "gem thingy"

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember this show I used to watch. It was a girl, she had blond hair and she lived with her mom. The theme song at the beginning of the show was like "would you like to swing from a star". She could stop time and her dad was an alien or an astronaut. She would go upstairs and talk to him through this gem thingy.

Comment: I've downvoted for a lack of research.

Comment: Welcome here! Funnily, I wanted to ask about this sitcom a few days but couldn't find how to describe the communication device. "gem thingy" is a nice addition to my vocabulary

Comment: Moonbeams home in a jar! So many flashbacks.

Comment: Dang, now I have that theme song stuck in my head :-)

Answer (score 38):

You are thinking of ["Out Of This World"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_This_World_(TV_series)), which ran on NBC in the late 80s.

> The series revolves around Evie Ethel Garland - a young girl who discovers on her thirteenth birthday that her father Troy is an alien from the planet Antares Prime, in the Scorpio Galaxy. Evie's half-alien heritage gives her superhuman abilities, with most of the episodes revolving around Evie misusing her powers and causing some trouble which she spends the rest of the episode fixing

Comment: As I just confirmed through the Wikipedia link, the series was also syndicated.  I checked because I remember watching it on a non-NBC channel.

Comment: This is listed in a few places as "worst sitcom ever". I watched the first one, and honestly it wasn't as bad as I expected. I'm sure there are worse ones out there.

Comment: @Almo There's always "Small Wonder" to lay a convincing claim to that title.

Comment: Uh yeah, that's pretty bad. :o

Comment: I was an 80's kid, I enjoyed both shows.

Comment: Worst according to Rotten Tomatoes: https://screenrant.com/21-worst-sitcoms-ever-made-according-rotten-tomatoes/